# How to preserve non-ASCII characters in ogr2ogr import?

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr, import

I want to import a list of international place names and their locations into a SQL Server database using ogr2ogr.

The source data is a CSV file encoded in UTF-8.

I've prepared a five-record sample file called `london_points.csv`. It contains the records for London in Arabic, Czech, English. Russian, and Chinese. It looks like this:

```
LanguageCode,Name,Longitude,Latitude
"ar","لندن","-0.143555","51.577222"
"cz","Londýn","-0.143555","51.577222"
"en","London","-0.143555","51.577222"
"ru","Лондон","-0.143555","51.577222"
"zw","倫敦","-0.143555","51.577222"
```

To import the CSV file using ogr2ogr I created a VRT file called `london_points.vrt`. It tells ogr2ogr to import the data and derive a point column from the Longitude and Latitude columns. It looks like this:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="london_points">
        <SrcDataSource>london_points.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

ogr2ogr apparently successfully imports all five records into tempdb:

```
$ ogr2ogr --DEBUG ON -s_srs EPSG:4326 -lco GEOM_TYPE=geography -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes" london_points.vrt
OGR: OGROpen(london_points.vrt/014AFF40) succeeded as VRT.
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: EstablishSession(Connection:"server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes")
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(DRIVER=SQL Server;server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes)
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table london_points.
OGR: OGROpen(MSSQL:server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes/0338CFF0) succeeded as MSSQLSpatial.
OGR: OGROpen(london_points.csv/033A41C8) succeeded as CSV.
MSSQLSpatial: DeleteLayer(london_points)
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table london_points.
OGR2OGR: 5 features written in layer 'london_points'
ODBC: SQLDisconnect()
VRT: 5 features read on layer 'london_points'.
CSV: 5 features read on layer 'london_points'.
```

I use a query like this to inspect the results in the database:

```
SELECT languagecode, name, longitude, latitude
FROM tempdb.dbo.london_points;
```

The result set looks like this:

```
languagecode name         longitude latitude
------------ ------------ --------- ---------
ar           Ù„Ù†Ø¯Ù†     -0.143555 51.577222
cz           LondÃ½n      -0.143555 51.577222
en           London       -0.143555 51.577222
ru           Ð›Ð¾Ð½Ð´Ð¾Ð½ -0.143555 51.577222
zw           å€«æ•¦       -0.143555 51.577222
```

The result set contains the correct number of rows. The `languagecode`, `longitude`, and `latitude` columns, which contain only ASCII characters, contain the correct values.

But all the non-ASCII characters in the `name` column are mangled!

The main [ogr2ogr documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) mentions no switch that controls character encoding.

The [CSV driver documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html) states only that *"All CSV files are treated as UTF-8 encoded."*

Is this a limitation of ogr2ogr, or am I missing some magic switch somewhere?

**Is there a problem with the GDAL SQL Server driver configuration?**

Andre Joost asked: *"Maybe it is a problem at the GDAL SQL Server driver site. Have you looked at [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx), AutoTranslate section?"*

The two [documented values for `AutoTranslate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx) are `yes` and `no`. It's not explict, but I think `yes` is the default value.

SQL Server automatically maps the code points for extended characters between different ANSI (single-byte) character sets. If you disable the translation behaviour, character data could get mangled if the client and the server are using different code pages.

The stored data type is Unicode (nvarchar) rather than ANSI (varchar) so I don't think setting would have an effect here.

I'll import the data once with translation explicitly disabled and again with it explicitly enabled to see if there is a difference.

In this example, the connection string contains `autotranslate=no`:

```
$ ogr2ogr --DEBUG ON -s_srs EPSG:4326 -lco GEOM_TYPE=geography -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=no" london_points.vrt
OGR: OGROpen(london_points.vrt/012AFF40) succeeded as VRT.
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: EstablishSession(Connection:"server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=no")
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(DRIVER=SQL Server;server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=no)
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table london_points.
OGR: OGROpen(MSSQL:server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=no/0335E048) succeeded as MSSQLSpatial.
OGR: OGROpen(london_points.csv/033732D8) succeeded as CSV.
MSSQLSpatial: DeleteLayer(london_points)
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table london_points.
OGR2OGR: 5 features written in layer 'london_points'
ODBC: SQLDisconnect()
VRT: 5 features read on layer 'london_points'.
CSV: 5 features read on layer 'london_points'.

SELECT languagecode, name, longitude, latitude
FROM tempdb.dbo.london_points;

languagecode name         longitude latitude
------------ ------------ --------- ---------
ar           Ù„Ù†Ø¯Ù†     -0.143555 51.577222
cz           LondÃ½n      -0.143555 51.577222
en           London       -0.143555 51.577222
ru           Ð›Ð¾Ð½Ð´Ð¾Ð½ -0.143555 51.577222
zw           å€«æ•¦       -0.143555 51.577222
```

In this example the connection string contains `autotranslate=yes`:

```
$ ogr2ogr --DEBUG ON -s_srs EPSG:4326 -lco GEOM_TYPE=geography -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=yes" london_points.vrt
OGR: OGROpen(london_points.vrt/02DCFF40) succeeded as VRT.
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: EstablishSession(Connection:"server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=yes")
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(DRIVER=SQL Server;server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=yes)
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table london_points.
OGR: OGROpen(MSSQL:server=.;database=tempdb;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=yes/0344E048) succeeded as MSSQLSpatial.
OGR: OGROpen(london_points.csv/034632D8) succeeded as CSV.
MSSQLSpatial: DeleteLayer(london_points)
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table london_points.
OGR2OGR: 5 features written in layer 'london_points'
ODBC: SQLDisconnect()
VRT: 5 features read on layer 'london_points'.
CSV: 5 features read on layer 'london_points'.

SELECT languagecode, name, longitude, latitude
FROM tempdb.dbo.london_points;

languagecode name         longitude latitude
------------ ------------ --------- ---------
ar           Ù„Ù†Ø¯Ù†     -0.143555 51.577222
cz           LondÃ½n      -0.143555 51.577222
en           London       -0.143555 51.577222
ru           Ð›Ð¾Ð½Ð´Ð¾Ð½ -0.143555 51.577222
zw           å€«æ•¦       -0.143555 51.577222
```

The results are identical.

**What SQL statements does ogr2ogr send to server?**

I traced the import using [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to capture the SQL statements that ogr2ogr uses to insert data in to the `london_points` table.

The trace captured these insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[london_points] (ogr_geometry, [languagecode], [name], [longitude], [latitude])
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-0.143555 51.577222)',4326), 'ar', 'Ù„Ù†Ø¯Ù†', '-0.143555', '51.577222');
go
INSERT INTO [dbo].[london_points] (ogr_geometry, [languagecode], [name], [longitude], [latitude])
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-0.143555 51.577222)',4326), 'cz', 'LondÃ½n', '-0.143555', '51.577222');
go
INSERT INTO [dbo].[london_points] (ogr_geometry, [languagecode], [name], [longitude], [latitude])
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-0.143555 51.577222)',4326), 'en', 'London', '-0.143555', '51.577222');
go
INSERT INTO [dbo].[london_points] (ogr_geometry, [languagecode], [name], [longitude], [latitude])
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-0.143555 51.577222)',4326), 'ru', 'Ð›Ð¾Ð½Ð´Ð¾Ð½', '-0.143555', '51.577222');
go
INSERT INTO [dbo].[london_points] (ogr_geometry, [languagecode], [name], [longitude], [latitude])
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (-0.143555 51.577222)',4326), 'zw', 'å€«æ•¦', '-0.143555', '51.577222');
go
```

For clarity I split each INSERT VALUES statement across two lines.

Inspecting the SQL reveals two problems.

ogr2ogr mangles the values for the `name` column before they reach the server. This proves the problem lies with ogr2ogr.

ogr2ogr passes the values as varchar literals (`'abc'`) rather than nvarchar literals (`N'abc'`). Even if the query text contained the correct characters, the server would replace with a question mark any character that don't exist in the default code page.

This query shows the difference:

```
SELECT 'لندن' AS varchar_value, N'لندن' AS nvarchar_value
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Londýn', N'Londýn'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'London', N'London'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Лондон', N'Лондон'
UNION ALL
SELECT '倫敦', N'倫敦';

varchar_value nvarchar_value
------------- --------------
????          لندن
Londýn        Londýn
London        London
??????        Лондон
??            倫敦
```

My default code page is Windows-1252. It contains characters for English and Czech, so varchar string literals are fine for these languages. Arabic, Russian, and Traditional Chinese supported only in Unicode, so all the characters are replaced by question marks.

I believe now that this is a fault in the OGR MSSQLSpatial driver.

Comment: In my browser it looks like the Arabic row swapped the Name and Latitude values. Is it a quirk of bidirectional text? Notepad++ renders it in the same way. ogr2ogr and SQL Server seem to put the values (mangled or not) into the correct columns.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem at the GDAL SQL Server driver site. Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx, AutoTranslate section?

Comment: @AndreJoost Thanks! I didn't know about that setting. Unfortunately, it had no effect this time. See my edit for more details.

Comment: The arabic line should be ok. If I copy the text into notepad++ and change encoding to ANSI, the fields are in correct order. It's just a pain to remove the quotations around the coordinates with arabic right-to-left order activated ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have same problem, my understanding is that the stored data is correct, if you consider it a binary utf-8 encoded data, to convert this data to nvarchar i wrote this (partially tested) UDF function in sql server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION varbinUTF8_to_nvarchar ( @data VARBINARY(MAX) )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @n INT
    DECLARE @buffer NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @buffer = N''
    SET @n = DATALENGTH(@data)

    DECLARE @i INT
    SET @i = 0

    DECLARE @byte INT
    DECLARE @byte2 INT
    DECLARE @byte3 INT
    DECLARE @byte4 INT

    DECLARE @decoded NCHAR

    WHILE @i < @n
        BEGIN
            SET @i = @i + 1
            SET @byte = SUBSTRING(@data, @i, 1)
            IF ( @byte < 0x7f )
                SET @decoded = NCHAR(@byte)
            ELSE
                IF @byte & 0xe0 = 0xc0
                    BEGIN
                        SET @i = @i + 1
                        SET @byte2 = SUBSTRING(@data, @i, 1)
                        SET @decoded = NCHAR(( ( @byte & 0x1F ) * 0x40 )
                                             + ( @byte2 & 0x3f ))       
                    END
                ELSE
                    IF @byte & 0xf0 = 0xe0
                        BEGIN
                            SET @i = @i + 1
                            SET @byte2 = SUBSTRING(@data, @i, 1)
                            SET @i = @i + 1
                            SET @byte3 = SUBSTRING(@data, @i, 1)
                            SET @decoded = NCHAR(( ( @byte & 0xF )
                                                   * 0x1000 ) + ( ( @byte2
                                                          & 0x3f ) * 0x40 )
                                                 + ( (@byte3 & 0x3f) ))
                        END 
                    ELSE
                        IF @byte & 0xf8 = 0xf0
                            BEGIN
                                SET @i = @i + 1
                                SET @byte2 = SUBSTRING(@data, @i, 1)
                                SET @i = @i + 1
                                SET @byte3 = SUBSTRING(@data, @i, 1)
                                SET @i = @i + 1
                                SET @byte4 = SUBSTRING(@data, @i, 1)
                                /*
                                EDIT 2014-11-27 THIS PART WERE WRONG
                                SET @decoded = NCHAR(( ( @byte & 0xF )
                                                       * 0x1000 )
                                                     + ( ( @byte2 & 0x3f )
                                                         * 0x40 )
                                                     + ( ( @byte3 & 0x3f )
                                                         * 0x40 )
                                                     + ( (@byte4 & 0x3f) ))
                                 FOLLOWS PATCH, but sql server does not support unicode chars > 16 bit
                                */
                                SET @decoded = NCHAR(( ( @byte & 0x7 )
                                                       * 0x40000)
                                                     + ( ( @byte2 & 0x3f )
                                                         * 0x1000 )
                                                     + ( ( @byte3 & 0x3f )
                                                         * 0x40 )
                                                     + ( (@byte4 & 0x3f) ))


                            END 
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                return  N'BAD UTF-8 MESSAGE'
                            END 

            SET @buffer = @buffer + @decoded

        END 
    return  @buffer
END
```

Then i can convert the wrong formatted field using something like:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.varbinUTF8_to_nvarchar(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), name_1) )
FROM
    dbo.che_adm1
```

In your specific case you should be able to get nvarchar data doing :

```
SELECT languagecode, dbo.varbinUTF8_to_nvarchar(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), name) as name, longitude, latitude
FROM tempdb.dbo.london_points;
```

Best Regards
Andrea

Comment: +1 for your heroic efforts, Andrea! The varbinUTF8_to_nvarchar function does recreate the correct NVARCHAR values. Would be able to share your workaround with the GDAL team on [ticket #5239](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5239)? Your response should encourage them to fix the driver properly.

Comment: Looks like someone has [committed a fix](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/27746) for this issue two months ago. Until that is released, I will accept this as a the best answer.

Comment: This issue is still not fixed, even on GDAL 2.0.0 (beta2). Many thanks for the workaround Andrea.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** a problem of the ogr csv driver.

When I load your data into QGIS as delimited text, the encoding is preserved.
Only thing QGIS is crazy about is that lat and lon should not be in quotation marks. 
But in the attribute table all name entries look good.

Furthermore, transforming with ogr2ogr to kml and gml gives correct output files.

So the error must be on the SQL Server export side.

If noone comes up with a solution, it might be worth asking at the gdal-dev mailing list, or opening a bug ticket at http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/report.

Maybe this ticket: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2339 has not been fixed correctly. Or the variable types in your database need special attention, as mentioned in the ticket.

The way ogr handles unicode encoding is documented here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc23_ogr_unicode

Comment: Thanks for the links. After inspecting the SQL that ogr2ogr generates (see my latest edit), I now believe this problem is a fault in the OGR MSSQLSpatial driver. I'll open a ticket with the GDAL team. If fidning a solution lies with the GDAL team, what should we do with the question here?

Comment: In the ticket, you can link here; and leave a link to your ticket here. And when the bug is fixed, you can report back here which GDAL version is running as expected.

Comment: [Done](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/70820/20590). I hope this is resolved soon!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a defect in the OGR MSSQLSpatial driver.

I raised [ticket #5239](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5239) with the GDAL team to address the defect.

I'll update this answer when the ticket is resolved.

Comment: Can you run your test again with GDAL 1.10? Just to make sure the problem is not solved already. http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/ always has the latest binaries.

Comment: Version 1.10.0 has the same defect. I downloaded the [version 1.10.0 MSVC2010 Win64 zip file](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/Download.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-1-10-0-mapserver-6-2-1.zip), extracted it, ran SDKShell.bat, and repeated the loading process. The output was the same.