# Export GeoJSON to MSSQL with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr

I'm testing this command to migrate GeoJSON data to MSSQL table:

`ogr2ogr -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=geodb;trusted_connection=yes" test.json -nln test`

It works beautifully, but if json data contains other characters then ASCII I get garbage in MSSQL table for that field:

[image]

Json file is UTF-8 encoded without BOM header.

I tried appending `-lco ENCODING=UTF-8` parameter to `ogr2ogr` command, but that didn't help.

So I wonder if anyone knows how to set sqlserver and ogr2ogr to communicate Unicode?

Comment: I would make a test by converting first into GML and then to MSSQL. If needed, check the charset parameter of the GML file and perhaps run the file through iconv. Not for a final solution but it may give more information about what is going on.

Comment: It's just the same. Both GeoJSON and now converted GML, render fine in UTF-8 text editor, but not in database table.

Comment: I do not believe that -lco ENCODING=UTF-8 has any effect because the driver does not seem to have such layer creation option http://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html. This issue may deal with http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530 and http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5239.

Comment: So this task is impossible currently. Thanks for the information.

Comment: No, I don't believe it is impossible but we just do not know what happens. There are people using MSSQL with GDAL and probably also with UTF-8 and I haven't read about similar problems before. I suggest to ask the question on the gdal-dev mailing list where the real experts are.

Comment: Well, open ticket you linked and [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70708/how-to-preserve-non-ascii-characters-in-ogr2ogr-import) show that there is no way to import Unicode with org2org to mssqlserver. UTF-8 data is passed to mssqlserver, but it doesn't recognize it as such because the column type is set to `varchar` instead `nvarchar`. If column is set to `nvarchar`, mssqlserver would apparently import UTF-8 data and convert it on the fly to it's Unicode encoding variant - UTF-16LE.